# sharepoint hide administrator header for non-admin

Tags: templates, sharepoint, permissions

I'm new to Sharepoint and I try to create application pages (via visual studio).

I want to see the design of the pages without the administrator header and the left column. I want to see the page only without anything else to summarize.
Of course I tried to log-in with a read only user but i can't figure out how to remove those for the non-admin.

Is-it a permission setting? Or is it a template setting? Or something else?

Sorry if the question is stupid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if it is the best solution but I created a custom master page with code-behind to show/hide the unwanted parts depending on the rights.

Maybe some others solutions would be quicker but I had to create a master page for design reasons anyway.

Answer (score 0):

For the header, I have done this before by putting a control on the page which checks to see if the current user is an admin or not and if they are not an admin, the following CSS is added to the page

div#s4-ribbonrow
    {
        display: none;
    }